# Is there a way to split a long line of code in VCL?

Tags: syntax, varnish, varnish-vcl, fastly

I can't figure out how to split a long line of code in VCL. I have checked the Varnish [docs](https://varnish-cache.org/docs/) and Fastly's, and I can't find anything except [this](https://varnish-cache.org/docs/7.4/reference/vtc.html#words-and-strings) regarding VTC files, which I also tested and didn't work with strings, probably due to indentation.

I find it hard to believe that the language doesn't allow splitting long lines or that the docs don't have a single example.

```
if (req.url.path ~ "^/stuff/otherstuff/(?:[a-z0-9_]+)(?:/(?:2018|2018_2019|2019|2019_2020|2020|2020_2021|2021|2021_2022|2022|2022_2023|2023|2023_2024|2024))?(?:/(?:cool|story|bro)(?:/.*)?)?/?$") {
    # do something
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [long strings in VCL](https://varnish-cache.org/docs/trunk/reference/vcl.html#strings) to spread your regex string across multiple lines.

However, the newline character is going to interfere with your regex. The way to tackle this is by adding `(?x)` to your regex to ignore the newlines in your pattern.

Here's the VCL to do it:

```
sub vcl_recv {
    if(req.url ~ {"^(?x)/[a-z]+
        [0-9]+"}) {
        return(synth(200));
    }
    return(synth(400));
}
```

Calling `/abc123` would return `200`. Calling `/foo` would return `400`.

Here's a `varnishtest` proof of concept:

```
varnishtest "multiline regex"

varnish v1 -vcl {
    backend default none;
    sub vcl_recv {
        if(req.url ~ {"^(?x)/[a-z]+
        [0-9]+"}) {
            return(synth(200));
        }
        return(synth(400));
    }
} -start

client c1 {
        txreq -url "/abc123"
        rxresp
        expect resp.status == 200

        txreq -url "/foo"
        rxresp
        expect resp.status == 400
} -run
```

Your can run this by putting the test case in a VTC file (e.g. `multiline-regex.vtc`) and then run `varnishtest multiline-regex.vtc` to run the test and validate the proof of concept.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer! Although splitting the regex fits my case, I'd also like to know if it's possible to split lines of code.

Comment: @thlink splitting lines of code is not an issue at all. For strings (like your regex) it's a lot more tricky because of the newlines. For non-string literals it's a lot easier. You can easily split an if-statement across multiple lines.

Comment: You are right and the example shows how. Thank you